# selenium+junit+ jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, jmeter

any one using selenium scripts with jmeter for performance testing

Comment: Can you accept some answers since people have given their time to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using Selenium to create JMeter tests. Unfortunately JMeter does not really handle the "chatter" that AJAX applications create because it sends the requests when it thinks it needs to.

There was a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/ff783c828632afd5/9955d31cbd38b513?) on the Selenium users group where people were trying to do this. None of them seem successful.

If you want to do load testing with Selenium I suggest that you have a look at [Browsermob](http://browsermob.com/performance-testing) as they take Selenium tests and then pass them out to do the load testing.